# How can I pass state to grandparent so that uncle/aunt can use it?

Tags: reactjs

I've been struggling for hours trying to get some code to work. I'm new with React, but I have spent a lot time looking for a solution to this as well, and updating this code as I understood with no success.

Basically my app is a component that splits into two components, with one of those splitting into 9 buttons. When I click one of those buttons, I want its uncle/aunt to recognize that, and use the id of the button that was pushed to create a message.

I figured I should be passing the button id up to the grandparent so that it can pass the id down to the uncle/aunt. But its the passing the id to the grandparent I'm struggling with.

This is the general set up below:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "x" : " "
    };
  getX(x){
    this.setState({"x": x})
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <A getX={this.getX}/>
      <B x={this.state.x} />
    </div>
    )
  }
}


const A = (props) => {
  const getX = (x) => props.getX(x);
  a = [];
  for (let i=0; i<9; i++) {
    a.push(<C id={i} getX={getX}/>);
  return <div>{a}</div>
}


class C extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "id" : props.id,
      "getX" : (x) => props.getX(x)
    }
    this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
  }
  handleMouseDown(e) {
    this.state.getX(e.target.id);
  }
  render() {
    <div />
  }
}


class B extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      "x" : props.x
    }
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.x}</div>
  }
  
}
```

Firstly, the `getX()` method of the App component doesn't seem to be working how I expected it to. By that I mean, when I add `getX("7");` to the render method of the App component, just before the return statement, the whole thing crashes. But if I replace `this.setState({"x": x})` with `this.state.x = x` in the getX() method, then the state sucessfully passes down to the component B, which is something at least. But, I don't understand why.

Secondly, I can't work out how to modify the App component's state from within component A. The getX() method of the App component doesn't seem to be passed into component A as I expected. Again, if I insert `getX("7");` before the return statement of component A, the whole thing crashes again. I expected the getX function of component A to be the same function as the getX method of the App component, and therefore update the state of the App component. But I've had no success with that at all. I've even tried inserting `this.getX = this.getX.bind(this)` into the constructor of the App component, but that didn't solve everything for me.

Lastly, as you can probably guess, I cant modify the App component's state from any of the C components.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your example so that it works. A few things:

1. Dont copy props to state, that is an antipattern and creates bugs (as you have seen). Dont copy the id or the function passed from component A to component C, or in component B. Just use the props values.
2. You had some syntax errors that I fixed.
3. You didnt return the array created in component A.
4. (This is my preference, but I will argue that you are *setting* a value, not *getting*, so i renamed `getX` to `setX`.)
5. There was nothing returned from component C. I was not sure what you was suppoosed to be returning from that component, so I just created a button with a click-handler.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            x: '',
        };

        this.setX = this.setX.bind(this);
    }

    setX(x) {
        this.setState({ x: x });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <A setX={this.setX} />
                <B x={this.state.x} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const A = (props) => {
    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        a.push(<C id={i} setX={props.setX} />);
    }

    return <div>{a}</div>;
};

class B extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.x}</div>;
    }
}

class C extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.handleMouseDown = this.handleMouseDown.bind(this);
    }

    handleMouseDown() {
        this.props.setX(this.props.id);
    }

    render() {
        return <button onClick={this.handleMouseDown}>Click me</button>;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't thank you enough for this. I transformed the structure of my actual code to match the structure of yours, and it worked perfectly.